Median of a Poisson-Binomial distribution
Let $Z$ be a random variable following a Poisson-Binomial distribution with parameters $(p_1, \dots, p_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i > \frac{n}{2}$. Consider the following two properties:
-If $n$ is odd: $P\left(Z \geq \frac{n+1}{2}\right) \geq \frac{1}{2}$.
-If $n$ is even: $P\left(Z \leq \lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor - 1\right) \leq P\left(Z \geq \lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor + 1\right)$.
I want to prove them or exhibit a counterexample. I have tried usual concentration inequalities such as Hoeffding but they are not tight enough to prove the result.

What is a 'Poisson Binomial' distribution?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution

Therefore you mean $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ such that the $X_i$ are independent with $\Pr(X_i=1)=p_i=1-\Pr(X_i=0)?$

Yes, this is what I mean by the definition.
